# Type definition breaking issue with `.svg` module and global at the same time

Tags: typescript

I am facing a weird issue with a custom definition file. You can see in the attached video but long story short:

1. If I don't have `export {}` then imports with `.svg` works fine, but the `Window` properties are not inferred
2. If I have `export {}` then the `.svg` stops working, but the `Window` properties work fine

Any reason why this is happening? You can also see this from the attached images.

[image: SVG working]

[image: SVG not working]

Comment: Without `export`, your declaration file is an **ambient declaration file**, meaning it is applied globally without needing to import or triple-slash reference it. However, a *global augmentation* requires it to be in a *module file*, which is any file that has a static import or export. When you remove `export {};`, you break your global augmentation, but you fix your other module augmentations, and vice versa.

Comment: @vr. I would lie if I would say that I get this 100%? any solution that you can think of?

Comment: Use two separate declaration files. One for your global augmentation and the other for the "normal" augmentations.